# Sencha ExtJS Submit two values

Tags: extjs

I have the below combobox code. Based on what user enters as first two characters I pull out some options through Ajax request and have user select one. The problem is right now I set it to send "fieldValue1.'|'.fieldValue2" values of the field with | separator in between. I want to know if there's a way to send fieldValue1 and fieldValue2 separately without requiring to do a separator?

```
xtype: 'combo',
autoLoad: true,
hideTrigger: true, 
fieldLabel: 'Product',
displayField: 'Description',
valuefield: 'fieldValue1.'|'.fieldValue2',
name: 'product',
queryMode: 'remote',
queryParam: 'entry',
typeAhead: true, 
minChar: 2,
store: {
    fields: ['text', 'value'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: TradeTransfer.Global.TradeTransferAPI + '/Requests/searchcommoditycodes',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    },
    sorters: [{
        property: 'Exchange',
        direction: 'ASC'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to hold multiple properties of the selected record, one way is to have a extra property in the combobox and set it during the `select` event:

From https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?82033-Multiple-Value-binding-with-combo

```
var hidden = new Ext.form.Hidden({
    name: 'userid'
});
var combo = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    ...
    displayField: 'username',
    valueField: 'id',
    hiddenName: 'id',
    listeners: {
        select: function(combo, record, index){
            hidden.setValue(record.get('userid'));
        }
    }
});
```

But depending of your objective, you can use `hiddenName` property (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-hiddenName)

> The name of an underlying hidden field which will be synchronized with
>   the underlying value of the combo. This option is useful if the combo
>   is part of a form element doing a regular form post. The hidden field
>   will not be created unless a hiddenName is specified.